# How to represent 1-to-many relationship in as3.0 data model

Tags: database, apache-flex, actionscript-3, model, data-modeling

I'm building an AS3.0 model for reading from an sqlite database.  I've successfully got it working with a simple table. Basically I have a databasemodel class with some shared functions and from it I extend classes, theoretically for each table on the database, but also for 'views' ie combinations of data on different tables when I need to mix things up.
Some of the events have tags stored in a separate table, and I'm wondering about the best way to handle those.. should I include an array in the event class and work with it that way, or separate each tag/cluster of tags into their own class? The tags are predefined and will be edited basically in the same places as if just another property of the event. However many events are imported and can only be edited by changing the tags.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to solve from this.

Comment: Are you talking about how to query the database? or how to display the data?

Comment: both, though moreso query. i know how to query. but i want to set up the queries in such a way that it's straightforward to display. Basically I'm asking, as far as a class with properties assigned from a query which can then be used to display the proprties, what's the best way to break it down in a case like this